Derivation of the Euler-Lagrange equation in Evans, PDE, section 8.1.2. p.432~434 ( Calculation of $i'(\tau)$ )
I am reading the Evans, PDE, section 8.1.2. and stuck at some calculation.
Suppose now $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is a bounded, open set with smooth boundary $\partial U$, and we are given a smooth function $L : \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R} \times\bar{U} \to \mathbb{R}$, called the Lagrangian. Define $I[w]$ for smooth functions $w : \bar{U}\to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying the boundary condition $w= g$ on $\partial U$ by $I[w] := \int_U L(Dw(x),w(x),x) dx$.
Then in the p.433, for any smooth function $v \in C^{\infty}_{c}(U)$, he define $ i (\tau) := I[u +\tau v] $ $(\tau \in \mathbb{R}$ ) ( assuming $u$ is a smooth function which is minimizer of $I[\cdot]$ ; See p.433 for more detail ). So,
$$ i(\tau) = \int_UL(Du+\tau Dv, u+ \tau v, x) dx \tag{8}$$
Thus
$$ i'(\tau) = \int_U \sum_{i=1}^{n}L_{p_i}(Du + \tau Dv, u+\tau v ,x )v_{x_i} + L_z(Du+\tau Dv , u+\tau v , x ) v dx.$$
Can anyone explain this calculation of $i'(\tau)$ more friendly?

This is just chain rule, the function is of the form $\tau \mapsto F(x(t), y(t), x_0)$

@ArcticChar : Yes. You are right. Thanks
